# PJSIP Compilation for all Targets arm64 (arm64-v8a), x86, or armv7

Tags: android, pjsip

I am compiling PJSIP Code with help of [documentaion](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#BuildingPJSIP)

At a time I am able to compile for one target but I want to compile for all targets. So how can I take all .so files for all targets.

I am following below commands for one Target.

```
TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags

APP_PLATFORM=android-19 ./configure-android
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: id you find the answer to this? I'm stuck with the same issue.

Comment: anybody has solved that?